# MongoDB query through php driver returns no resutls

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

So I have a php script on a web server listening for mongoDB queries via a JSON object POST with another page building and sending queries to the php service. All my standard queries such as :
`{"field1":"2342342","field2":"234234"}` are sent and return the correct resutls.

However, when I try to send a query that includes a range of values it returns nothing.

```
{"field2":"1234","date" : {$gte : "2013-02-11"},"date" : {$lte : "2013-02-11"}}
```

I can go into the command line and call:

```
db.collection.find({"field2":"1234","date" : {$gte : "2013-02-11"},"date" : {$lte : "2013-02-11"}} )
```

which returns the results as expected. Obviously there is something going on that I do not fully understand.

PHP command doing the search:

```
$c_collection->find(json_decode($request));
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is `$request` built?

Comment: I have a number of fields on a form that, when search is hit, builds the JSON string and sends it(ajax POST) to the php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to search the database using a duplicate element name.  MongoDb would issue an error such as this while performing this search:

```
Duplicate element name 'date'.
```

You need to place your range within the same block.  For example:

```
{
    'date': {
        $gte:"datehere",
        $lte:"datehere"
    }
}
```

In PHP:

```
$criteria = array('date' => array('$gte' => 'datehere', '$lte' => 'datehere'));
```

Then use that json as your criteria.

Also, why are you decoding the criteria before passing it to the database?  The method can accept an array just fine.

Comment: Nevermind in regards to decoding the criteria.  I had misunderstood and now I see that you are building a json string instead of an array before sending it.

Comment: You are correct. There was an additional issue of the dates being strings and the comparison of them. There was not anything else going on. Now getting results from:  {"runDateTime" : {"$gte" : "2013-02-04" , "$lte" : "2013-02-04Z"}}